# How to conduct A/B test with ColdFusion?

Tags: testing, web-applications, user-interface, coldfusion, ab-testing

I heard of A/B testing.  Conceptually it's easy to understand but practically, how shall one carry out such test?

Is this something easily doable with CF and some cookie / session tracking or should this be used together with tools like Google Analytics?  If we make use of CGI and session/cookie, What should be collected?

Comment: I might be wrong, but this feels like a way too broad a question for SO at the moment.  you might want to refine it a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look into Mark Mandel's [Squabble](https://github.com/markmandel/Squabble). It's an A/B testing solution that's written in CF. It hasn't been updated in a while but Mark presented on it at cf.Objective in 2012, so it's compatible with ACF 9, at least.